# Android. How play video on Surface(OpenGL)

Tags: android, video, opengl-es

Need to help

1. How play video on `Surface(OpenGL)` in Android? 
   I tried playing video in `mySurfaceView extends SurfaceView` with help method `setSurface()` in `MediaPlayer`.

   ```
   SurfaceTexture mTexture = new SurfaceTexture(texture_id);
   Surface mSurface = new Surface(mTexture);
   MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
   mp.setSurface(mSurface);
   ```

I got only playing audio - video not playing.

2. How get video buffer for sending in `OpenGL`??
3. How playing video on `GLTexture`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play video in OpenGL on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363162/how-to-play-video-in-opengl-on-android)

Comment: @Bart `This question was voluntarily removed by its author` is what it says..

Comment: @SERPRO He then did so after asking this question, which is essentially the same.

Answer (score 32):

From android source code...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;

class VideoSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    VideoRender mRenderer;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

    public VideoSurfaceView(Context context, MediaPlayer mp) {
        super(context);

        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mMediaPlayer = mp;
        mRenderer = new VideoRender(context);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        queueEvent(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    mRenderer.setMediaPlayer(mMediaPlayer);
                }});

        super.onResume();
    }

    private static class VideoRender
        implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer, SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener {
        private static String TAG = "VideoRender";

        private static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
        private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
        private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET = 0;
        private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET = 3;
        private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
            // X, Y, Z, U, V
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 0.f, 0.f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 1.f, 0.f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 0.f, 1.f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 1.f, 1.f,
        };

        private FloatBuffer mTriangleVertices;

        private final String mVertexShader =
                "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
                "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
                "  vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
                "}\n";

        private final String mFragmentShader =
                "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                "precision mediump float;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                "}\n";

        private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
        private float[] mSTMatrix = new float[16];

        private int mProgram;
        private int mTextureID;
        private int muMVPMatrixHandle;
        private int muSTMatrixHandle;
        private int maPositionHandle;
        private int maTextureHandle;

        private SurfaceTexture mSurface;
        private boolean updateSurface = false;

        private static int GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES = 0x8D65;

        private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

        public VideoRender(Context context) {
            mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                mTriangleVerticesData.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
            mTriangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0);

            Matrix.setIdentityM(mSTMatrix, 0);
        }

        public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer player) {
            mMediaPlayer = player;
        }

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (updateSurface) {
                    mSurface.updateTexImage();
                    mSurface.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);
                    updateSurface = false;
                }
            }

            GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
            checkGlError("glUseProgram");

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);

            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

            Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);

            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
            checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
            GLES20.glFinish();

        }

        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {

        }

        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
            mProgram = createProgram(mVertexShader, mFragmentShader);
            if (mProgram == 0) {
                return;
            }
            maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
            if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition");
            }
            maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord");
            if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord");
            }

            muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
            if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix");
            }

            muSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uSTMatrix");
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uSTMatrix");
            if (muSTMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uSTMatrix");
            }


            int[] textures = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

            mTextureID = textures[0];
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);
            checkGlError("glBindTexture mTextureID");

            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                                   GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                                   GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

            /*
             * Create the SurfaceTexture that will feed this textureID,
             * and pass it to the MediaPlayer
             */
            mSurface = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureID);
            mSurface.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);

            Surface surface = new Surface(mSurface);
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
            surface.release();

            try {
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "media player prepare failed");
            }

            synchronized(this) {
                updateSurface = false;
            }

            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }

        synchronized public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            updateSurface = true;
        }

        private int loadShader(int shaderType, String source) {
            int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
            if (shader != 0) {
                GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
                GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
                int[] compiled = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
                if (compiled[0] == 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader " + shaderType + ":");
                    Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
                    GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
                    shader = 0;
                }
            }
            return shader;
        }

        private int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
            int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
            if (vertexShader == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
            if (pixelShader == 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
            if (program != 0) {
                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
                checkGlError("glAttachShader");
                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
                checkGlError("glAttachShader");
                GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
                int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
                if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ");
                    Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
                    GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
                    program = 0;
                }
            }
            return program;
        }

        private void checkGlError(String op) {
            int error;
            while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
                Log.e(TAG, op + ": glError " + error);
                throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
            }
        }

    }  // End of class VideoRender.

}  // End of class VideoSurfaceView.
```

Comment: can you provide an example of how to keep the video aspect ratio? So for example to only stretch height but still maintain the aspect ratio?

Comment: You can see https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/blob/master/vitamio-sample/src/io/vov/vitamio/demo/VideoViewSubtitle.java

Comment: there is no any onFrameAvailable callback, if I am trying to set as media player datasource some live stream url. What might be a problem?

Comment: The answer is not quite correct. You forgot to mention that preparing MediaPlayer in GLThread will cause IllegalStateException since it is blocking the thread.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can't. At least that's what i found out.
My plan was to have some sort of OpenGL scene (text ticker) while playing a video.
Since android uses HW decoding for displaying a video, it will not be done with OpenGL. I also tried to play the video in OpenGL using ffmpeg but i found out, that no device i tried with, was performant enough to do SW decoding via ffmpeg.

So I had to use a VideoView to display my video and put a GLSurfaceView on top of it, to view my ticker text.
But you have to make the GLSurfaceView translucent like in ApiDemos done with 'TranslucentGLSurfaceViewActivity'.

Another thing i realized: If you put a GLSurfaceView on top of a VideoView your fps breaks down dramatically from 60fps (opengl) to about 30-40fps.
This applied to all 2.x versions of android i tested.
Last week i had the chance to test it on Android 4 and this time i got no break down in fps. Maybe they really improved graphics pipeline for ICS.

Greetings, -chris-

Answer (score 1):

I just converted the Java to Kotlin version

```
internal inline fun <T> glRun(message: String = "", block: (() -> T)): T {
    return block().also {
        var error: Int = GLES20.glGetError()
        while (error != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            error = GLES20.glGetError()
            Log.d("MOVIE_GL_ERROR", "$message: $error")
            throw RuntimeException("GL Error: $message")
        }
    }
}

class MovieRenderer: GLSurfaceView.Renderer, SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener {

    private var program = 0
    private var textureId = 0

    // Handles
    private var mvpMatrixHandle = 0
    private var stMatrixHandle = 0
    private var positionHandle = 0
    private var textureHandle = 0

    // Surface Texture
    private var updateSurface = false
    private lateinit var surfaceTexture: SurfaceTexture

    // Matrices
    private var mvpMatrix = FloatArray(16)
    private var stMatrix = FloatArray(16)

    // float buffer
    private val vertices: FloatBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(VERTICES_DATA.size * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        .asFloatBuffer().also {
            it.put(VERTICES_DATA).position(0)
        }

    var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

    @Synchronized
    override fun onFrameAvailable(surfaceTexture: SurfaceTexture?) {
        updateSurface = true
    }

    override fun onDrawFrame(gl: GL10?) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (updateSurface) {
                surfaceTexture.updateTexImage()
                surfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(stMatrix)
                updateSurface = false
            }
        }

        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT or GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        glRun("glUseProgram: $program") {
            GLES20.glUseProgram(program)
        }

        vertices.position(VERTICES_POS_OFFSET);

        glRun("glVertexAttribPointer: Stride bytes") {
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                VERTICES_STRIDE_BYTES, vertices)
        }

        glRun("glEnableVertexAttribArray") {
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle)
        }

        vertices.position(VERTICES_UV_OFFSET)

        glRun("glVertexAttribPointer: texture handle") {
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                VERTICES_STRIDE_BYTES, vertices)
        }

        glRun("glEnableVertexAttribArray") {
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureHandle)
        }

        Matrix.setIdentityM(mvpMatrix, 0)

        glRun("glUniformMatrix4fv: mvpMatrix") {
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0)
        }

        glRun("glUniformMatrix4fv: stMatrix") {
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(stMatrixHandle, 1, false, stMatrix, 0)
        }

        glRun("glDrawArrays: GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP") {
            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)
        }

        GLES20.glFinish()
    }

    override fun onSurfaceChanged(gl: GL10?, width: Int, height: Int) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    }

    override fun onSurfaceCreated(gl: GL10?, config: EGLConfig?) {
        program = createProgram()
        positionHandle = "aPosition".attr()
        textureHandle = "aTextureCoord".attr()
        mvpMatrixHandle = "uMVPMatrix".uniform()
        stMatrixHandle = "uSTMatrix".uniform()
        createTexture()
    }

    private fun createTexture() {
        val textures = IntArray(1)
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0)
        textureId = textures.first()
        glRun("glBindTexture textureId") { GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureId) }

        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST)
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR)

        surfaceTexture = SurfaceTexture(textureId)
        surfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this)

        val surface = Surface(surfaceTexture)
        mediaPlayer?.setSurface(surface)
        surface.release()

        try {
            mediaPlayer?.prepare()
        } catch (error: IOException) {
            Log.e("MovieRenderer", "media player prepare failed");
            throw error
        }

        synchronized(this) {
            updateSurface = false
        }

        mediaPlayer?.start()
    }



    private fun String.attr(): Int {
        return glRun("Get attribute location: $this") {
            GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, this).also {
                if (it == -1) fail("Error Attribute: $this not found!")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun String.uniform(): Int {
        return glRun("Get uniform location: $this") {
            GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, this).also {
                if (it == -1) fail("Error Uniform: $this not found!")
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES = 0x8D65

        private const val FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4
        private const val VERTICES_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES
        private const val VERTICES_POS_OFFSET = 0
        private const val VERTICES_UV_OFFSET = 3

        private val VERTICES_DATA = floatArrayOf(
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, 0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
        )

        private const val VERTEX_SHADER = """
            uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
            uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;
            attribute vec4 aPosition;
            attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;
            varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
            void main() {
                gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;
                vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;
            }
        """

        private const val FRAGMENT_SHADER = """
            #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
            precision mediump float;
            varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
            uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
            void main() {
              gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
            }
        """

        private fun createShader(type: Int, source: String): Int {
            val shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type)
            if (shader == 0) throw RuntimeException("Cannot create shader $type\n$source")
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source)
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader)

            val args = IntArray(1)
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, args, 0)
            if (args.first() == 0) {
                Log.e("MOVIE_SHADER", "Failed to compile shader source")
                Log.e("MOVIE_SHADER", GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader))
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader)
                throw RuntimeException("Could not compile shader $source\n$type")
            }

            return shader
        }

        private fun createProgram(vertexShaderSource: String = VERTEX_SHADER,
                                  fragmentShaderSource: String = FRAGMENT_SHADER): Int {

            val vertexShader = createShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderSource)
            val fragmentShader = createShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderSource)

            val program = GLES20.glCreateProgram()
            if (program == 0) throw RuntimeException("Cannot create program")

            glRun("Attach vertex shader to program") {
                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader)
            }

            glRun("Attach fragment shader to program") {
                GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader)
            }

            GLES20.glLinkProgram(program)
            val args = IntArray(1)
            GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, args, 0)

            if (args.first() != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
                val info = GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program)
                GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program)
                throw RuntimeException("Cannot link program $program, Info: $info")
            }

            return program
        }


        private fun fail(message: String): Nothing {
            throw RuntimeException(message)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mMediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(mSurfaceTexture));
```

You can use above line of code to use it on your mediaPlayerObject over your desired surfaceTexture which is a applied texture over your surfaceview.

Hope that helps.