# Stream youtube video for Google Cardboard - Android

Tags: android, youtube, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I want to stream a 360 video from YouTube in my android app in such a way that it is compatible with Google Cardboard- that is, I want the video to be streamed side by side like in CardboardView.

I have been searching the internet about this and I don't seem to have much luck with it. So any amount of help would be heavily appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you check the official SDK https://developers.google.com/cardboard/overview I'm sure there must be something there.

Comment: the official SDK doesn't seem to have anything specific about playing videos, let alone streaming from youtube. Do let me know if you find anything relevant there. I have been looking too! @Budius

Comment: I just read a bit on it. Apparently `CardboardView` is an extension of `GLSurfaceView`. That means that all the cardboard stuff is run directly over OpenGL (which makes sense). So probably you next step of research should be how to show videos through a OpenGL view. This maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375598/android-how-play-video-on-surfaceopengl

Comment: @Budius I did use the VideoSurfaceView from the link you mentioned, it plays the video perfectly well, but two more things to add to it-
1) support for playing 360 videos and 2) split the screen into 2 and play it side by side for Google cardboard. I'm a newbie with opengl and VR. I'd really appreciate if you could help me any more with this!

Comment: and 3) it has to stream from youtube, and not play from resources or the sdcard!

Comment: Hi, did you resolved it ?