# Does GCSVideoView work with YouTube 360-degree live streaming?

Tags: ios, youtube, google-cardboard, google-vr

I saw this announcement today about YouTube streaming 360 video, https://youtube.googleblog.com/2016/04/one-step-closer-to-reality-introducing.html

Does GCSVideoView loadFromUrl: work? Code below modified from VideoWidget iOS sample doesn’t show 360 video...

```
NSString *videoPath =@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Db-uq08ydI4";
[_videoView loadFromUrl:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:videoPath]];
```

Excited to see this working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870607/stream-youtube-video-for-google-cardboard-android?rq=1) answer's

I'm really looking forward to see a working answer to this... Working myself into a possible solution..

What I found out is that `GCSCardboardView` is an  extension of `GLSurfaceView`. All the Cardboard Viewports and Proyections are on top of OpenGL. I'm no expert but the way to go (for me) is 'How to show videos through an OpenGL view'.

Second step would be: Create a Pixel Buffer in OpenGL to support video stream.. that's where i'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The Google VR SDK is made to turn a 360º video file into the VR environment. Youtube is an HTML page. If you could access the stream directly, you would be able to use the GVRVideoView.