# Load 360 degree video on youtube using VrVideoView (Google VR SDK)?

Tags: android, youtube, google-cardboard, google-vr

I want to load a 360 degree video, which is on youtube, in an native android app using VrVideoView (Google VR SDK).

Looking at [the android api reference here](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/video/VrVideoView.html#loadVideo(Uri)), it doesn't seem to be supported, 
but it [seems to be available for iOS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707121/does-gcsvideoview-work-with-youtube-360-degree-live-streaming)?

Is there anyway to do this on android? Thanks

Comment: ,Did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: Sorry no, I don't think its supported

Answer (score 2):

You can't play YouTube videos in custom video player because of YouTube content policy.

Even if you get video stream URL, your application will be rejected from Google Play.

The only thing you can do is to use [Android YouTube player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

Comment: this is the same for iOS app??

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the case of a 360 YouTube video it is 'Mono 360 uses a single pano.'

You can solve this problem by changing `VrVideoView.Options`

```
VrVideoView.Options options = new VrVideoView.Options();
options.inputType = VrVideoView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
videoWidgetView.loadVideoFromAsset("<your local youtube video>", options);
```

if you are not integrated sdk yet here is the .
[link](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/get-started)

for more info [link](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I was looking for a way to play youtube videos directly from a youtube url. Btw, I think there are stereo 360 videos on youtube too!

Comment: @dosa got any solution for this?

Comment: @shivamDev sorry, I am not working on this anymore :)

Comment: @ShivamDev Have you got any solution on this?

Comment: @ShivamDev Have you try Youtube Android Player API?